# Sunburst chart in excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm missing the Series Options under "Data series" to resize the doughnut size hole. I tried add-ins and save as and  hasn't changed.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info? Include screen caps if you think it will help (upload to http://imgur.com and link to them). Also, please take the time to read [this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you provide your sample?